# Get last 3 months record from paid salary table where month and year is stored in separate column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need help with the MySQL query. I have a table like this in MySQL

What I want is to get the last 3 months' records from the table. But I don't understand how to make this MySQL query.

I have tried to contact both columns and tried to generate a MySQL date to compare but it returns me null.

I also tried this query and it works for current data. But i am not sure if it is the only way to do this or is there any better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want is to get the last 3 months' records from the table.

I think you want a `where` clause like this:

```
date(concat_ws('-', salary_year, salary_month, 1)) >= (curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate()) day) - interval 2 month
```

The key idea here is to convert the string to a date so it is handled correctly.

If you have a fixed date, then you would represent that as:

```
date(concat_ws('-', salary_year, salary_month, 1)) >= '2021-04--01'
```

Comment: actually it is a data range so it is not fixed to get data like 3 months or 6 months

Comment: @ManojDhiman . . . This answers the question that you asked here (which is repeated in the question, by the way).  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.

Comment: The second solutions worked for me. Thanks